# Why can't Superuser highlight Powershell syntax but SE Android App can?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

In [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1325042/726810) I added a small Powershell script. In Firefox and Chromium, that code doesn't show syntax highlighting. I'm using latest Firefox and Chromium browsers and don't want to change it.

- Here is the screenshot in PC:

[image: PC_Chromium]

But Stack Exchange Android App can highlight the syntax colors.

- Here is the screenshot in Android:

[image: Android_SE_App]

Thanks to DavidPostill who shares [this meta thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362286/8928481) link. It says to add `<!-- language: lang-coffee -->` before PS script. With this tweak, that script shows color in both cases.

- My question: Why it doesn't show color (without that tweak) in PC but does show in Android?

Comment: SO does not use it's own code syntax highlighting.  SO issues Google Code Prettify.  If something is not working it should be reported [here](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues) likewise Google Code Prettify [does not support PowerShell](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/README.md#for-which-languages-does-it-work).  Since The iOS and Android are more or less community projects, it is very likely they are using something else, to identify code syntax.

Comment: Because the mobile applications feature set are different than the desktop client.  In other words, the mobile application displays the data in a different way.  Which is the reason some community moderation features are not accessible in the mobile application

Comment: Seems like an interesting bug; maybe ask this on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: Can you migrate this to Meta SE?

Comment: `lang-coffee` is just a workaround, just like people use `lang-dos` or `lang-vb` for batch files. Interesting things is that bash has its own syntax highlighting support but batch and powershell don't